# Connecting to a service on a host behind NAT from another host behind NAT over the Internet

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, port, forwarding

Assume you have a host (*hosta*) that is running a TCP service (e.g. a VNC server on port 5901). You want to access to this service from another host (*hostb*) running a VNC client. Both hosts are connected to Internet, but there are some restrictions:

**1. *hosta* can be reached from the Internet using any of its TCP ports**

VNC client on *hostb* connects to *hosta:5091* directly.

**2. *hosta* can be reached from the Internet only through SSH**

From *hostb*:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 usera@hosta
```

VNC client on *hostb* connects to *localhost:5901*

**3. *hosta* cannot be reached from the Internet (e.g. it is behind CGN / CGNAT). However, *hostb* can be reached from the Internet**

From *hosta*:

```
ssh -R 5901:localhost:5901 userb@hostb
```

VNC client on *hostb* connects to *localhost:5901*

**4. *hosta* and *hostb* cannot be reached from the Internet. They are behind CGN / CGNAT; they can only create outbound connections**

We can use another host (*hostc*) which can be reached from the Internet using ssh.

From *hosta*:

```
ssh -R 5555:localhost:5901 userc@hostc
```

From *hostb*:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5555 userc@hostc
```

VNC client on *hostb* connects to *localhost:5901*

I have a case like the 4th scenario above, but I do not wish to use a third host (*hostc*), mainly because of performance and cost reasons.

What are my alternative (cheaper [=free] and better performance) options?

---

**Note 1:** I have tested and determined that although [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) does *not* work in my case, [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) ***does*** work. However, I need a tool that will establish connection oriented (similar to TCP) session over UDP that will utilize UDP hole punching.

**Note 2:** Failing to use any of "UDP hole punching" programs available on the Internet, I decided to write my own. I am still improving it, but, as it is, it works fairly well. You can find it [here](https://www.kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?python_udphp).

Comment: Not sure that you'd be able to get away from using a commonly accessible (third) machine, in your fourth use case.  Alternatives to SSH would include virtual private LANs (e.g., Hamachi) or VPNs, both of which (in your case) would still require a third party.

Comment: You haven't much alternatives here: either one of NATs should be configured for port forwarding or external host should be used.

Comment: @montonero yup.  but at times, that isn't the case. EG - brother and sister go to 2 different universities, and both are behind NAT and have no ability to change configuration at either end.

Comment: @ivanivan in this case some intermediate host should be involved. to make a connection you'll need to have an open port at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Tor and tor hidden services is one option. It technically still assumes usage of some third host, but in our case that will be a chain of multiple such hosts: hosta <-> hostc1 <-> hostc2 ... <-> hostb

It's not that fast, but it's free, opensource and secure.

Also, the similar option will be any other overlay networks. From the top of my head: I2P, FreeNet, GNUnet